# fifo queue in Firebase

Tags: ruby, firebase

I'm trying to implement a FIFO queue in Firebase using only the REST API and the Ruby wrapper (https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby).

```
firebase.push('queue', { :name => 'Bob' })
firebase.push('queue', { :name => 'Sally' })
firebase.push('queue', { :name => 'John' })
```

And I want this to return 'Bob' since it was the first element added.

```
firebase.get('queue', { :limit => 1 })
```

I've tried using priorities but I'm either not able to set them properly using the Ruby wrapper or I'm not able to retrieve based on the priority order (highest first).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the priority field in firebase, however, the documentation for the Ruby wrapper is incorrect. The docs suggest using

```
response = firebase.push("todos", { :name => 'Pick the milk', :priority => 1 })
```

The priority field is actually '.priority' and it's expecting a symbol so you'll need to use something like this instead:

```
response = firebase.push("todos", { :name => 'Pick the milk', :".priority" => 1 })
```

Comment: @mdesantis firebase client documentation fixed:  https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby/issues/79#event-1317848707